# Determining the efficiency of a biometric system

Tags: biometrics, identification

How can find the efficiency of any biometric system is there an equation to find it?

How is the efficiency of a biometric security system?

Comment: How would you measure efficiency?  Ratio of input to output? What is the input? Number of claimants processed? Is it possible you want to measure the *effectiveness* of a biometric system?

Comment: if we have this scenario how can find the efficiency  ?

EXAMPLE:

let us assume we have a fingerprint biometric system. We also, have 100 users. During the enrollment stage 5 users where not able to enroll (e.g we can not establish a fingerprint signature/template for them). This means the system has a Failure to Enroll Rate (FER) = 5%. This means only 95 users can use the system.

Comment: Are you only looking for enrollment efficiency? That's going to be dependent on the people (bodies) being enrolled. A person with no fingers cannot be enrolled either. Is it valid to assign an efficiency rating to such a system? Most rating systems deal with the running of the system, not enrollment.

Comment: This is just simple example but I want to know how calculate the efficiency of any biometric system ??

Comment: Is this an exam question?

Comment: @nuha I understand your desire, but you have not defined it. For operation efficiency, Cross over error rate is a common method, but that comes up as the first Google result. Assuming you know about CER, how else are you defining 'efficiency'?